# Animating growth

Tags: animation, texturing, topology

[image]So let's say I want the make a low-poly 3d character that has a beard. He is a hero for a game concept and uses his beard the travel and fight the bad guys.  My question is, how do I properly build my character so I am able to animate his beard growth? How do I properly animate it? Finally, how would that process effect the texture? 
Thanks
Brandon H

Comment: Maybe post images with shortest beard and with the longest. Also tell us if you want to export it to some game engine if yes - where? And lastly if it will be using image based texture, then yes changed shape will affect it.

Comment: I do plan on exporting this character to Unity.  Other than image based textures, what kind of texture can I use that would be good for a growing asset like my characters beard?  I added a quick sketch of what I want to achieve with the beard growth.  Thank you for helping me out :)